# Make command work once and for 1 user only until next bot order is posted

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am currently trying to make so if a new order is posted in the discord channel, the  first user to write !accept gets a message thrown back to them in chat, while if people after first guy tries to write !accept will get an error message. How should I do this?

AcceptCommand Class:

```
public class AcceptCommand : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("Accept")]
    public async Task order()
    {
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder();

        var UserID = Context.User.Username;

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("<@&468001483099471883>");
        embed.AddField("Order has been taken by booster", "__" + UserID + "__", true);
        embed.AddField("The CEOS will provide you with account details \nfor the boost in PM as fast as possible.", "_ _ ", false);

        embed.WithColor(new Color(253, 000, 00));

        embed.WithCurrentTimestamp();

        embed.WithFooter("WaveBoosting Order Fetcher", "https://i.imgur.com/DNMWntW.png");

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);

    }
  }
}
```

OrderCommand Class:

```
 public class OrderCommand : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("Order")]
    public async Task order()
    {
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder();

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("<@&468001483099471883>");
        embed.WithAuthor("Order Available");
        embed.AddField("Platform", "STEAM", true);
        embed.AddField("Gamemode", "2V2", true);
        embed.AddField("Rank", "DIAMOND1 → CHAMPION1", true);
        embed.AddField("Price", "69,33 €", false);
        embed.AddField("_ _ ", "_ _ ", false);
        embed.AddField("Accept this order by typing  **!ACCEPT**", "_ _ ", false);

        embed.WithColor(new Color(38, 244, 22));

        embed.WithCurrentTimestamp();

        embed.WithFooter("WaveBoosting Order Fetcher", "https://i.imgur.com/DNMWntW.png");

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would personally accomplish this is something along the lines of the following.

1. Add a unique identifier to your orders as they come in.
2. Display the unique identifier along with the rest of the order.
3. Require the !Accept command to take in a unique identifier.
4. When the !Accept command is called check against a Dictionary of stored accepted commands
5. If it is there already than send that is is already accepted by someone else.
6. Else give it to that user.

Some code below....  I took out a lot from your example above but it should give you the idea. Need to make sure whatever container you use to store these orders is concurrent. I would recommend a ConcurrentDictionary, but this is a pretty typical way of doing something like this. 
NOTE: Your Dictionary needs to reside somewhere other then your command class... Command classes are created and destroyed on an on needed basis.

```
public class AcceptCommand : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("Accept")]
    public async Task order([Remainder]string uniqueID)
    {
        if(SomeDictionaryOfAcceptedOrders.ContainsKey(uniqueID){
            //Someone already accepted
        } else {
            //Give it to the caller
            SomeDictionaryOfAcceptedOrders.Add(uniqueID, "Person accepting order"); 
        }
     }
}


public class OrderCommand : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("Order")]
    public async Task order()
    {
        var uniqueID = //UUID, SomeRandomHashValue, Whatever that will be unique to this order;
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("<@&468001483099471883>");
        embed.WithAuthor("Order Available");
        embed.AddField("Unique Order ID", uniqueID, true);
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);
    }
}
```